# Angular Routing: Avoid destroy of active component after changing the url?

Tags: angular, routes, components

The click on

```
[routerLink]="['/ComponentB']
```

will result to an another instance of the ComponentB displayed in the

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This behaviour is what I like to avoid, as I like to reuse a allready existing instance which should be linked to the router-outlet.

---

If you have a formula collection which handles a couple of ng components which are basely build on a collection / array of class objects hold approx. 10 props e.g. include input values, nominal value and at least units and Booleans …, so to keep the page status (input+results) ends into duplicate a lot of stuff.

Therefore, I simulate a routing by using *ngif to display the related parts (component s) of the single page but never change the url.

```
<div *ngIf="visibleComponentA>
... All part of ComponetA 
  ></div>
```

CpmponetA.html

```
<div *ngIf="visibleComponentB>
... All part of ComponetB 
  ></div>
```

CpmponetB.html

This Boolean will be set inside the relate code of the component:

```
@Input()visibleComponentA: boolean = true;
```

ComponetA.ts

Now in the top page

```
<div (click)="OnClickNav(visibleComponentA)" >ComponentA</div>
<div (click)="OnClickNav(visibleComponentB)" >ComponentB</div>
```

app.component.html

and the method *OnClickNav(Selected:NavFlags)* switching the correct visible status of the component.

```
OnClickNav(Selected:NavFlags){

    Selected.NavStatus=!Selected.NavStatus

    Selected.NavItem=='visibleComponetA'? this.visibleComponetA.NavStatus=Selected.NavStatus: this.visibleComponetA.NavStatus= false;
    Selected.NavItem=='visibleComponetB'? this.visibleComponetB.NavStatus=Selected.NavStatus: this.visibleComponetB.NavStatus= false;
```

app.commonet.ts

The class *NavFlags* is simple

```
export class NavFlags {
  NavItem: string = '';
  NavStatus: boolean = false;

  constructor(NavItem: string, NavStatus: boolean) {
    this.NavItem = NavItem;
    this.NavStatus = NavStatus;
  }
}
```

nav-flags.ts

By this the "individual" pages will not leave an no data are lost. I have no duplicated store.

By clicking the button, it is possible to navigate through the page in components without loss of data.

This hack is not perfect, so maybe there will be better way to solve this angular matter.

Comment: Not loss of data means ?

Comment: I relaise, that every navigation by changing the url (router-outlet) will result to an new instance of the related component, while the older one will not destroy and is remaining all time. E.g. if this component will be displayed on the "top" page app.component.html and ADDITIONAL a routing is given and the same componentB.ts is displayed in <router-outlet></router-outlet> both will have differ values (as they are differ instances).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display two components on one page at a time, You can use different `outlets`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'A', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'B', component: BComponent, outlet: 'secondRouter' }
];
```

and in your HTML:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='secondRouter'></router-outlet>
```

Check this [StachBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-router-outlet) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tipp with the 2nd route outlet, however, this not working as I split my app into differ module,ts and at least inside this individual modules I have implemented the const routes:Route={...} and the route outlet is into the app.component.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bigger problem than it seems. However, there's still hope and I hope you follow Angular guidelines and build the component accordingly, and have a module with a component as `entryComponent` in your route config.

THAT `entryComponent` will be the main entry component of your module which you can store the component information when you route.

So maybe you can try creating the components in the main component, and the main component will retain the info of the components it created.

But do take note that this will not work if you switch between modules.

Another possible solution would be to utilize a service to store the data you need.

Comment: This latest solution is done and works perfect! Into the servive I have a prop which hold the array of all variable (which will be used for staffolding the html page) similar as a store and an additional counter.  In the related component I inject the service and into OnInit() I implemented a check, that the component will not override be multible call the the stack.